# Name for data structure that keeps track of minimal/maximal element through unit step updates

Tags: data-structures

There's a data structure that has the following operations:

- $\text{init}(n)$ - Initializes $n$ integer elements set to zero, $O(n)$.
- $\text{inc}(i)/\text{dec}(i)$ - Increments/decrements the element at index $i$ by one, $O(1)$.
- $\text{get}(i)$ - Returns the element at index $i$, $O(1)$.
- $\text{min}()/\text{max}()$ - Returns an index containing a minimal/maximal value, $O(1)$.

One possible implementation of the above is a linked list of buckets, each bucket storing the elements of value $k$, combined with a vector storing which bucket an element $i$ is in, and a vector directly to the node inside the bucket.

Does this have a name?

Comment: You mean the name for the abstract data or the name for your approach?

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz Either, any references are appreciated.